# Querying tables with multiple "likes", is there another way?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 11 Columns; let’s call them Column1…..Column11.  Let’s say all those 11 columns house employee names. I’m trying to look for a specific record in all those 11 columns, but here’s the problem, some column house only last name, some last name and middle initial, some have last name and the middle name spelled out, and some have the full name.
So, I’m trying to find a better way to query all the tables.
What I’m currently doing is:

Select

Column1, Column2….Column11

From

Table

Where

Column1 like ‘Beatrice%’
OR

Column2 like ‘Beatrice%’
OR….

Column11 like ‘Beatrice%’

Is there a short query I can use like ‘IN’ with wild card?

Where

‘Beatrice%’ IN (Column1, Column2,… Column11)

I know this query won’t work, but I’m wondering if there is a shorter way to query the tables without having to use 11 “likes” with 11 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try following construct:

```
select distinct Column1, Column2, Column3, ...
from [Table]
    cross apply (values (Column1), (Column2), (Column3), ...) col(Value)
where col.Value like 'Beatrice%'
```

or

```
select Column1, Column2, Column3, ...
from [Table]
where exists (
    select 1 from (values (Column1), (Column2), (Column3), ...) col(Value)
    where col.Value like 'abc%'
)
```

Also you may consider use of SqlServer Full-Text Search capabilities ([link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx))

Comment: i-one, thanks for the tip. I haven't used it yet, but it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

More to the point, this is a good time to normalize your database. You have repeating columns, which always makes queries difficult.  Suppose you had an `employee` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [employee] (
    id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(20),
    middle_initial CHAR(1),
    surname VARCHAR(20)
)
```

and suppose now your `[table]`, which I will rename `[project]`, looked like:

```
CREATE TABLE [project] (
    id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    supervisor_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [employee](id)
)
```

Finally, to express the fact that projects have employees, add a link table:

```
CREATE TABLE [project_employee] (
    project_id INT REFERENCES [project](id),
    employee_id INT REFERENCES [employee](id)
)
```

Now, a query for projects with an employee like `%beatrice%` would just involve joins and a single employee without unions.  In fact, SQL Server supports computed columns, so add a computed column `full_name` to the `[employee]` table, and then you have a query like:

```
SELECT p.name, e.full_name
FROM project p
JOIN project_employee pe ON p.id = pe.project_id
JOIN employee e ON pe.employee_id = e.id
WHERE e.full_name LIKE '%beatrice%';
```

Yes, I know my syntax is wrong, but I hope you get the idea.  Either normalize the database, or keep on writing queries with unions.

Besides, what would you need to do were your employee Jane Doe to marry Richard Roe and take her husband's name, becoming Jane Roe? With your current database, you would need to search for Jane Doe in all the columns of your table and update them.  Renormalize, and it's just updating one row in the `[employee]` table.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the explanation and I definitely understand your logic of normalizing the database. I should've mentioned that these tables are actually a dimension table, and each column represents a node in the hierarchy.

Comment: Oh, so you anonymized the table then.  The use of `[table]` and `[Column1]` made it seem like a standard problem with normalization. With that assumption, I felt you were binding yourself to continued inefficiencies.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for misleading you in the wrong direction. I'll remember to include more details in the body of the question.

Comment: Still, techniques like using computed columns can help you with your `LIKE` phrases. Your table has a column that contains more than one piece of information; split the column up for clarity and becaus eyou may need the individual parts, but add a computed column for the whole thing.